# Any traditional sources that compare Itai the Gitti to Rus?

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, book-of-ruth

Are there any traditional sources comparing/contrasting Itai's deliberate choice to go with Dovid--after Dovid attempted to dissuade him--to Rus's deliberate choice to cast her lot with Naomi?

Shmuel II, Perek 15 (Itai goes with Dovid after Dovid tries to dissuade him)
Megillas Rus, Perek 1 (Rus goes with Naomi after Naomi tries to dissuade her)

An earlier question about Itai links to a contemporary comparison between the two: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/115045/27766